# HID: The 'Rate Controlled' connection 'app' access to protected services is denied

Tags: ios

We are getting the following error message in our app under certain circumstances.  It looks like we cannot perform any network requests.  The app launches successfully to the log in screen, but when it tries to contact our server to log in, we get this message.

```
HID: The 'Rate Controlled' connection 'appname' access to protected services is denied
```

Some facts:

- This is an ad hoc distributed app. We are testing it right now
- This particular tester is in Thailand right now, it had previously worked (with an earlier version) when he was in the US (the phone is from the US)
- It works on the same phone/os (iPhone 5/iOS 7.1) for someone in the US
- Facebook logs in successfully (using the Facebook SDK and native Facebook login)
- We get this message before we perform the http request, so it seems like a problem with initialization.

Comment: Having the same problem on a very small app.

Answer (score 1):

I see similar errors in a Cordova-based iOS application and I saw that iOS 7.1 contains security fixes related to the "IOKit HID Event" ([iOS 7.1 security content](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6162)). This may be related.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar networking problem and also saw this message. The message seems not to be related to networking, it has something to do with [HID](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/HID/intro/intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000970-CH202-SW1) and appears in my log every time I have a device connected via USB.

In my case the problem was caused by a missing server certificate on the device which might or might not have been removed during a recent iOS update.

Comment: Hi Dorian, what it means with "protected services" in this context?

Comment: I have no clue what the "protected services" are in this case, maybe some feature of the HID API. You can safely ignore this message unless you want to access HID devices from your app. In my case it was definetely a red herring.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in a small iOs application. The application worked without a problem in the simulator, and an older version (no difference in code just compiled earlier!) was working without problems for over a year. 
I seem to have solved the problem, but don't really understand why....

I was using the Bubblewrap library for RubyMotion, which uses the default libraries of iOs. I have now started using AFNetworking. 
The code that was causing the problem changed a field in the HTTP header. When I changed the code to not change the header, the problem was gone. Since the header change is essential for the backend I am using, I now use AFNetworking for communication.

The AFNetworking code looks like this:

```
client = AFMotion::SessionClient.build("http://www.example.com/") do
  session_configuration :default

  header "Authorization", "Basic #{user_info}"
  response_serializer :json
end
```

Comment: What was the header field change that caused the problem?