# Worklight 6.1 "access to protected services is denied" after app is deployed to App Store

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I have deployed an app to the `Apple App store`. Local and on device testing went fine, but when the app is loaded from the `App store` onto an `iOS 7.1` device, the user receives a **Access to Server is Disabled - Login Failed** dialog, followed by a solid white screen.

Looking at the phone console log, the following error appears:

`backboardd[31] <Error>: HID: The 'Rate Controlled' connection '<application name>' access to protected services is denied.`

Searching on Apple developer forums and StackOverflow show others having similar issues over the past few weeks, but with no clear resolution. This one in particular notes the same issue and that it may be related to Cordova: [HID: The 'Rate Controlled' connection 'app' access to protected services is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817782/hid-the-rate-controlled-connection-app-access-to-protected-services-is-deni)

If I turn off the Worklight Server, the app gives a standard Connection Failure message and continues to work properly in Offline Mode, except for any features that call server adapters.

Server and Worklight Studio are running Consumer Edition.

Not sure if this is an app specific code issue, a permissions problem in iOS, or a core conflict between `Cordova` and `iOS 7.1` (yesterday's 7.1.1 shows the same issue).

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you on the latest Worklight 6.1.0.1 fixpack level? Since you have the Consumer Edition you are entitled to full support; you may want to open a PMR to see if this is a bug.

Comment: Handly, any updates on this peculiar issue?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the 6.1.0.1 fixpack installation was not completing properly. While it looked ok at installation, if you watched the logs carefully, there were errors about halfway through. This may have been due to trying to upgrade a deployed app that was already on 6.1.0.1. Since the server only had the one app deployed, we undeployed and removed the app and associated war file. This allowed the fixpack to complete installation correctly.

Next, after re-deploying the app (same war file), to the server, we still got a protected services is denied error, but it no longer said “Rate Controlled”. The device error log then started reporting a version issue. The App Store app and the server version were both supposed to be “2.1”, but after we re-deployed the server version with “2.0”, the app started communicating with the server and adapters.

Finally, we still have an issue that the iOS version is not triggering direct updates for the app (same code, Android version does work properly). We have not yet needed an update, so will test this on our next App Store push.

Comment: Hi, we have the same problem ( i got ur reply on my own question thread) and i tried redeploy the app but still the problem persists. Would like to ask, how do you guys redeploy the fixpack? I tried the Update function in the IBM Installation Manager but it doesn't allow me to proceed as my server version is already at 6.1.01

Comment: In our case, I think the Fixpack never completed properly the first time. There were some error messages in the middle of the large log output, so it was easy to miss them unless you read the whole thing. If I were in your situation, I would probably just rebuild the server from scratch, but then I only had one app deployed, so would not have too much config to do for the rebuild.

Comment: I see. Sadly a rebuild is not possible in our situation. I'll try to explore further. Thank you =)