# IBM Worklight - App hang at splash screen after applying FixPack

Tags: ios, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

After applying FixPack 1 (for Worklight 6.1.01) on the device, we notice some unexpected behaviour in iOS. We had tried on both iOS 6 and 7.1 and they both display the same behavior.

We had increase the version number of the app (i.e. from 1.2 to 1.3) for the deployment. When the user try to update the app via the AppCenter Mobile Client, after installing, the app will just stop at the splash screen with the IBM logo. Only by delete / uninstall the app and reinstall again the app can work as per usual.

We check the console log in xcode and got the following print out:

```
May 26 13:16:42 MY-iPad profiled[713] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Service stopping.
May 26 13:16:42 MY-iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[714] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/284CEAF0-8B89-467C-BA55-0F277FFA6521 (sandbox)
May 26 13:16:42 MY-iPad backboardd[28] <Error>: HID: The 'Passive' connection 'MyMobileApp' access to protected services is denied.
May 26 13:16:42 MY-iPad MyMobileApp[714] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] -[WLCordovaAppDelegate handleAppWebResources:] in WLCordovaAppDelegate.m:373 :: NativeInitUntilWebViewLoad : START
May 26 13:16:42 MY-iPad MyMobileApp[714] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [OCLogger] Max file size exceeded for log messages.
May 26 13:16:42 MY-iPad MyMobileApp[714] <Warning>: Web resources integrity test is disabled.
May 26 13:16:42 MY-iPad MyMobileApp[714] <Warning>: Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
May 26 13:16:42 MY-iPad MyMobileApp[714] <Warning>: Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
May 26 13:16:42 MY-iPad MyMobileApp[714] <Warning>: Unlimited access to network resources
May 26 13:16:42 MY-iPad MyMobileApp[714] <Warning>: [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 15.210986ms
May 26 13:16:42 MY-iPad MyMobileApp[714] <Warning>: [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 17.367005ms
May 26 13:16:42 MY-iPad MyMobileApp[714] <Warning>: WARNING: AutoHideSplashScreen key in Cordova.plist is missing or set to NO! SplashScreen will display indefinitley unless you manually hide it. Set value to YES to autohide.
May 26 13:16:42 MY-iPad MyMobileApp[714] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] -[WLCordovaAppDelegate postInitOnMainThread:] in WLCordovaAppDelegate.m:303 :: NativeInitUntilWebViewLoad : END
May 26 13:16:42 MY-iPad MyMobileApp[714] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [OCLogger] Max file size exceeded for log messages.
May 26 13:16:42 MY-iPad MyMobileApp[714] <Warning>: Resetting plugins due to page load.
May 26 13:16:42 MY-iPad MyMobileApp[714] <Warning>: Failed to load webpage with error: The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

Some googling on the issue lead to this [Worklight 6.1 "access to protected services is denied" after app is deployed to App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23242860/worklight-6-1-access-to-protected-services-is-denied-after-app-is-deployed-to). It is a similar issue albeit with a different behaviour.

For now we had instructed the user to clear all their data before they upgrade the app, but we can't use this method going forward as there will be crucial data in the device that we can't erase simply for upgrading the app.

Any info or idea on this is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

We tried to redeploy the app by using the Server Configuration Tool but still the same problem persists. We checked the log for the Fixpack installation and there was no error reported. Also the IBM Installation Manager shows that the version installed is the latest 6.1.01 and it doesn't allow me to Update it, only Modify.

**UPDATE 2**

After deleting the `native` folder and redeploy the apps (from the `.wlapp` file to the `.ipa` file), the same issue still appear. However a pattern is observed.

If the app is rebuild and redeploy, the first install from the AppCenter will run as per usual with no problem, meaning the data will be preserved and the apps run normally, even though there are no changes in the code and version no. However if you click on the `install` button another time to install again, then the problem will appear.

Comment: What about this warning? "<Warning>: WARNING: AutoHideSplashScreen key in Cordova.plist is missing or set to NO! SplashScreen will display indefinitley unless you manually hide it. Set value to YES to autohide."

Comment: @IdanAdar based on observation, that warning does shows up even when the app is running ok (when we delete the app from device and install it back), and so we assume that the warning is not the cause for this issue.

Comment: we found this setting in the `config.xml` within the `native` folder: `<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />`

Comment: I posted our solution to the similar issue on the link above. Short version is that we had an incomplete 6.1.0.1 fixpack applied and then our App Store and server app version numbers were not matched. Our side effect was a little different - hung on a white screen and we did not have the AutoHideSplashScreen error, but it may be worth checking the fixpack and version numbers. Good luck!

Comment: @Handly Thanks for the info, we will try and check. We don't use the AppStore to distribute the app, just via the AppCenter IBM provided. Meanwhile i'll look into the Worklight version number in the app vs the one in the server. =)

Comment: @ipohfly, did Handly's suggest help?

Comment: @IdanAdar the installation on the server side have no issue, we're still yet to test on a redeployment of the WAR file. Need to get clearance on that since it's on production server already.

Comment: I suggest to try first on a test production environment, of course...

Comment: We are going to try on a development environment first of course.. still need clearance on that as we don't have direct access to all the servers =)

Comment: @IdanAdar We tried to redeploy the apps at server, but after doing it still having the same problem. We didn't rollback the server and redeploy the Fixpack though, as the Installation Manager doesn't allow Update.

Comment: @ipohfly, what happens if you delete the native folder and re-build the project?

Comment: BTW, after changing the version from 1.2 to 1.3, you also deploy the .wlapp to the server, right? in fact, even if not changing the verion number, after upgrading the server - you need to redploy the .wlapp. Try.

Comment: @IdanAdar yes, i redeployed the war file, .wlapp file and also the .ipa file at the AppCenter. Didn't try deleting the native folder though, will give it a shot.

Comment: @IdanAdar i just tried deleting the native folder and rebuild the app, the first install was ok, meaning the data is still there and the app can run as per usual. However if i were to install again from the mobile client without uninstalling the app, the error will occur.

Comment: does that include a version change?

Comment: no, we didn't change the version number.

Comment: btw, the test was carry out on iOS 6 device as our development server don't have SSL connection. Still trying to figure out how to test this out on iOS 7.1

Comment: @ipohfly, could you try again with the latest 6.1.0.1 iFix from IBM Fix Central? there was recently a fix regarding iOS and getting stuck on the splash screen. It might solve this issue.

Comment: @IdanAdar Yes Idan we had gotten a notification from EcuRep but currently we're having trouble trying to download the files from the FTP server. Checking with them for alternative route to get the files. Thanks for the notification!

Comment: I also work for IBM using Worklight 6.2 and iOS 6 and am having exactly the same problem. Please find a solution.

I also noticed that the error is not deterministic --- if you restart the app 2 or 3 times in a row, about 1 in every few times the app will actually startup successfully, but the rest of the times it will hang on the initial splash screen with exactly the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM had released a quick fix patch for the issue, and after installing onto the development server, things look fine.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out - there's a bug in worklight (not cordova).

In the file:

helloHelloIphone/Classes/hello.m, the Xcode debugger reported that the following auto-generated worklight code was loading an incorrect value for "startPage":

```
-(void)wlInitDidCompleteSuccessfully
{
    UIViewController* rootViewController = self.window.rootViewController;

    // Create a Cordova View Controller
    CDVViewController* cordovaViewController = [[CDVViewController alloc] init] ;

    cordovaViewController.startPage = [[WL sharedInstance] mainHtmlFilePath];
```

Because the value of “startPage” turned out to be:

```
       @"worklight:///Users/mrhines/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/A2E1427C-7DFF-4843-BF3D-0B7E4B470E43/hello.app/www/default/(null)”
```

This is clearly wrong - the end of the string should say “index.html”, not null.

So, by replacing the last line of code above with the following line:

```
       cordovaViewController.startPage = [[[WL sharedInstance] mainHtmlFilePath] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(null)" withString:@"index.html"];
```

My application reliably starts up and moves past the hung splash screen, fixing the bug in Worklight.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We had logged this issue with IBM Support, and they had release an early fix for us to try. I imagine that this fix will eventually be released as a patch in near future. Anyway, good catch on the root cause!